# E-Mail appearing in 'My Settings' but not in user profile?

Tags: development, user-profile, email, active-directory

As title suggests, there's a user who has confirmed he has his e-mail populated based on what they see in 'My Settings'. However, when I'm trying to do something in code with their e-mail I can't retrieve it. I noticed, for this particular user, that the user profile has no e-mail stored against them. Can anybody give me an idea why? Could it be active directory interfering somehow?

Edit, to clarify - I'm kind of looking for confirmation that the two e-mails are different fields and some discussion as to why (I have researched this but come up with nothing). I'm not really seeking advice or review on my code as it works fine on production (where the user profile service is thoroughly populated).